# One time binding: update model and re-render view

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

I was wondering if possible, using angular one time binding, to completely re-render the view/template after a model update, also by recompiling the template.
For instance, on a button press, maybe in the way react works: I update the model and explicitly force to update the view.
Basically here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
// controller
angular.module('app', []).controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
        {id: 1},
        {id: 2},
        {id: 3}
    ];

    $scope.addAndRefresh = function() {
        $scope.items.push({id: 4});
        // manually call render logic here???
    };
});


<!-- HTML template -->
<div ng-repeat="item in ::items">
    {{item.id}}
</div>
<button ng-click="addAndRefresh()">Add</button>
```

By clicking on the "Add" button I would like to refresh the view to see the newly added item.

Comment: Why would you want to completely re-render it, and not just the parts that are dependent upon the modified data?

Comment: That my same exact question: I am interestend in understanding how, and if possible, to manually re-render a one time binded template, no matter the data.

Comment: I'm afraid Stack Overflow is not the forum for such questions. Here you'll need to show code for what you have tried and explain what you are doing and why, so people can help you.

Comment: Bizzarre: I always thought stackoverflow is the right place for such a question. I have a clear problem (it seems to me) I do not know how to approach. Maybe someone wiser than me could help!

Comment: @MatteoPiazza Check my answer for a couple of solutions to your problem. Not built into the angular core, but it's probably as close as you will get to that until Angular 2.0.

Answer (score 13):

I was trying to figure out some way to do this elegantly as well.  I wish there was something built into the framework to refresh one-time bindings.  All I came up with is using ngIf to remove the element I wanted to refresh and the add it back.

Here's a demo.  Click the Add Item button, you'll see that the list does **not** refresh due to the one-time binding on the repeat.  Check the refresh values and click again, and the items will be updated:

```js
var app = angular.module('demo', []);

app.controller('RefreshCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  var counter = 4;

  $scope.visible = true;

  $scope.items = ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3'];

  $scope.addItem = function() {

    if ($scope.refresh) {
      $scope.visible = false;
    }

    $scope.items.push('Item' + counter);

    counter++;

    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.visible = true;
    });
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.17/angular.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="RefreshCtrl" class="container">
  <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addItem()">Add Item</button>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="refresh" />Refresh Values
  <div ng-if="visible">
    <h3 ng-repeat="item in ::items">{{item}}</h3>
  </div>

  <p>Items Array: {{items}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx, that's a way I was also exploring, but, like you, I was also looking for an elegant way.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Interestingly it only works when you use the `$timeout` function of Angular. Using the native JS `setTimeout()` function (which I tried at first) does not work - then the `visible` change does not get recognized by the view.

Comment: @MathiasConradt it is because setTimeout does not start new digest cycle. The cycle loops through all the watches (including ng-if) and refreshes/recompiles everything.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on what you are after, I would recommend one of two solutions:

- Get [angular-bind-notifier](https://github.com/kasperlewau/angular-bind-notifier).

  - Does **not** recompile your template, only refreshes the bound values.
- Get [kcd-recompile](https://github.com/kentcdodds/kcd-angular/blob/master/resources/kcd/directives/kcd-recompile.js).

  - Recompiles the template along with the bound values.

I'm the author of the former, and the big difference between it and other solutions is the choice of hooking into the `$parse` service.

As such, you can use the introduced `{{:refreshkey:expression}}`/`:refreshkey:expression` syntax in most *(if not all)* areas of Angular where an expression is accepted.

---

#### In your case, the implementation could look something like this:

**js**

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
      {id: 1},
      {id: 2},
      {id: 3}
  ];

  $scope.addAndRefresh = function() {
      $scope.items.push({id: 4});
      /**
       * '$$rebind' is the internal namespace used by angular-bind-notifier.
       * 'refresh' is the refresh key used in your view.
       */
      $scope.$broadcast('$$rebind:refresh');
  };
});
```

**markup**

```
<!-- HTML template -->
<div ng-repeat="item in :refresh:items">
    {{::item.id}}
</div>
<button ng-click="addAndRefresh()">Add</button>
```

---

#### Or, if you wanted something semi-dynamic

**js**

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
      {id: 1},
      {id: 2},
      {id: 3}
  ];

  $scope.add = function() {
      $scope.items.push({id: 4});
  };
});
```

**markup**

```
<!-- HTML template -->
<div bind-notifier="{ refresh: items.length }">
  <div ng-repeat="item in :refresh:items">
      {{::item.id}}
  </div>
</div>
<button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
```

---

Check out the [README](https://github.com/kasperlewau/angular-bind-notifier/blob/master/README.md) and this [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/mariwadeqo/edit?html,js,output) for some usage examples.

Comment: Beware of kcd-recompile. I recently discovered that child component scopes are not destroyed upon recompile. Over the course of a long session and several recompiles, this will bring things to a crawl. https://github.com/kentcdodds/kcd-angular/issues/8