# One-time binding with ng-repeat trackBy isn't updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to minimize the number of watchers in my AngularJS application by using both "track by" in my ngRepeat, as well as using one-time bindings.

e.g.

My View:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by trackingId(item)">
  {{ ::item.updated_at }}  {{ ::item.id }}
</div>
```

My trackingId and scope look something like this:

```
$scope.items = [
  { id: 1, updated_at: 'January 1, 2015' },
  { id: 2, updated_at: 'January 1, 2016' },
  ...
]

$scope.trackingId = function(item) {
  return item.id + '_' + item.updated_at;
}
```

Now, somewhere in my app, an items updated_at value gets changed. For example,

```
$scope.updateItem = function(item) {
  item.updated_at = Date.now();
}
```

I would then expect that the view to reflect this item as a "new" item in the DOM due to the trackingId value for that item being changed, thereby updating the one-time bound value, however this is not happening.

Is my understanding of one-time binding + trackBy incorrect? How can I achieve the above such that if my trackingId changed, the item will be re-drawn on the view?

Thanks,

Comment: I think the most elegant way of doing this is the bottom answer here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31271093/one-time-binding-update-model-and-re-render-view

Comment: Perhaps, but is my understanding of trackBy incorrect?

Comment: My understanding is that trackBy is so that if you wanted to replace the whole dataset, it would be able to quickly find the diff and only rerender that bit of the dom. one time binding on the other hand, is what it says on the tin - without some mechanism to update the value, it will never change. You are updating the value you have tagged as 'dont update me again' and are surprised it hasn't updated. You could add :: to the values you dont ever want to update again and leave the rest as normal - http://codepen.io/dmoojunk/pen/grdKyo

Comment: Well, wouldn't changing the tracking ID of something, make it appear that the item is "new" to the dataset? Shouldn't that update the array and act as if that element is a new item in the data set?

Comment: You are specifically marking it as '::don't watch this value'. Updating it rightly has no effect.

Comment: But wouldn't that still bind the value to the item that it sees from the trackingId? 

{{ ::item.updated_at }}   -> does it track that "particular" item, even though the item's tracking ID has changed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110305/discussion-between-arashb31-and-dmoo).

Answer (score 0):

When you update an item attached to scope, you have to let angular know that the binding has changed and to do that you use $scope.$apply().

```
 $scope.updateItem = function(item) {
  item.updated_at = Date.now();
  $scope.$apply();
}
```

Comment: I still don't see how this answers my question

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is not good idea

```
return item.id + '_' + item.updated_at;
```

try without this.for example only with id

Comment: Could you explain this with an example? I want the DOM to reflect the new "updated_at" value of the item, even though I'm using one-binding. How would just returning the ID help with updating the view?

Comment: If you use bindOne, it will not redraw it again. (Didn't see it)