# How to update one time binding property inside ng-repeat for an individual element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have list and it is repeated using ng-repeat with one time binding as below

```
<div ng-repeat="item in ::items"> 
 {{::item.name}}
</div>
```

When there is a change in the list for example add/remove I can update the  the items by broadcasting $$rebind:refresh event as below.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in :refresh:items"> 
 {{::item.name}}
</div>
```

Source: for the above way of doing is referenced from this [one time binding repeated items update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31271093/one-time-binding-update-model-and-re-render-view)

But for me I want to update individual item if something is changed on that time, here I can trigger same event but is there any elegant way to update individual item without refreshing entire list

Comment: Why do you need one time binding ?

Comment: You can simply go with two way binding and i am sure for few data it does not make a lot of difference.

Comment: @AKA you are right, we can use that for smaller list.. but I have huge data sets and performance will degrade if I use two way bindinig

Comment: You can make one way bind to those values that are just binded once and rest all others to two way binding.

Comment: I understand that but I want to make each item property one way binding and remaining things like ng-show and ng-hide or ng-if etc have two way binding already... here I want to minimise as many watcher as I can. Because I will  be having huge list of items in my application

Comment: You can just use ng-repeat in your items and use uni directionel binding in your element with ::item.name. You'll be able to push or remove element from your list.

Comment: @nevradub right... I mentioned that in  my question, I can pretty much refresh list.... but I want to edit item and update that item only (individual), I don't want to to re-render entire item list

Comment: If you want update element you can't use unidirectionel bindings.

Answer (score 0):

This will boost performance

```
<div ng-repeat="item in ::items track by $index"> 
    {{::item.name}}
</div>
```

Comment: You are right. But for my application track by $index won't work as I have drag and drop, so some time with this the new items are taking previous item properties when I do reordering.

Comment: yes but we aren't tracking with object's value we are tracking with angular's inbuilt props..Please try it because $index will generate new value when your array get a new object in it..dont know exactly it worked or not but you may try it